# after pressing browser's back button on firefox loading image keeeps on rotating

Tags: html, firefox, loading

I have div tag like this

```
<div id="page-loader">
<img src="loader.png" alt="loading"></img>
</div>
```

and script will run for every click on "a" tag

```
$("#page-loader").show();
```

whenever there is a click on `<a>` tag browser shows "loader.png" pic and moves to new page(depends on href). after I clicked firefox's back button, it goes to last page and shows "loader.png" pic and it keeps showing "loader.png" pic not at all stopped. Could someone please help me on this..?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you click back, you're effectively going back to the state of the `div` being shown. You could set your jQuery to always hide the div when initially loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page-loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried the way u told but no use. some other way? and no problem on IE.